# Changing dynamically created div contents using jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm getting pretty frustrated here.

I have a table of records.  Next to each record will be a button.  On clicking the button next to that record, a jquery AJAX call should be executed.

```
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function swapContent(cv) {
    $("#myDiv").html('<div align="center"><img src="images/loader.gif"/></div>').show();
    var url = "process.php";
    $.post(url, {contentVar: cv} ,function(data) {
       $("#myDiv").html(data).show();
    });
}
//-->
</script>
```

The associated HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv" align="center"><a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('do_stuff');"><img src='images/icon.png' border='0'></a></div>
```

When I click on the HTML link, the contents of the div "myDiv" are changed out for the output of the ajax call to process.php.  This is all well and good, but I will have dozens of these divs, and I need to be able to call the swapContent function with not only the parameter cv, but also pass in a parameter for which div should have its contents altered.

I believe my error is just based on an ignorance of JS syntax.  For instance, I've done this:

```
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function swapContent(thediv,cv) {
    $(thediv).html('<div align="center"><img src="images/loader.gif"/></div>').show();
    var url = "process.php";
    $.post(url, {contentVar: cv} ,function(data) {
       $(thediv).html(data).show();
    });
}
//-->
</script>
```

but I'm not sure if that is then treating the variable thediv as a string when it should be an object or what might be the problem.

I would appreciate any help you might give!

```
<div id="div1" align="center"><a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('div1','do_stuff');"><img src='images/icon.png' border='0'></a></div>
...
<div id="div2" align="center"><a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('div2','do_stuff');"><img src='images/icon.png' border='0'></a></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are passing the id of the div to the function
so, in place of `$(thediv)` ->  `$("#"+thediv)` will work

Comment: "arrrrrrrrrrgh" Don't you hate it when it's a silly syntax error?   I've had a really tough time debugging this.  I've just been using the Firefox Webdeveloper toolbar's Error Console.  Is there a better way?  For instance, I wasn't given a "div not found" error or somesuch to point me in the right direction.   Anyhow, thanks!!

Comment: @Bruce - The way jQuery works, the `$(someselector)` function will return a jQuery object containing the _zero or more_ elements that matched `someselector`, so there isn't really an applicable concept of a "div not found" error. (Though you can test how many elements matched, because the resulting object has a `.length` property.)

Comment: @Bruce, Install FireBug plugin in FF and then FireQuery plugin. It is a better way to debug jQuery code. I can't say about particular this case but its definitely better tool.

Answer (score 2):

You have already done most of the work :) . Now use `this` object. http://jsbin.com/evirun/2/edit#source ( *create one example to show how can you find out the correct calling div element* )

```
<div id="div1" align="center"><a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent(this,'do_stuff');"><img src='images/icon.png' border='0'></a></div>

<div id="div2" align="center"><a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent(this,'do_stuff');"><img src='images/icon.png' border='0'></a></div>
```

Now your script:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function swapContent(obj,cv) {
    $(obj).parent().html('<div align="center"><img src="images/loader.gif"/></div>').show();
    var url = "process.php";
    $.post(url, {contentVar: cv} ,function(data) {
       $(obj).parent().html(data).show();
    });
}
//-->
</script>
```

`this` will actually pass the DOM element which is calling the method. Then in your script you are using this element.

**EDIT**

I missed that `anchor` tag is inside `div` . Changed the script to use `parent`.

Comment: I would appreciate if you put a comment when going for downvote. That can help me understand the reason of downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the `onclick` and `onmousedown` handlers inline. I'd suggest you use (html5) `data-` attributes to store the value that you're currently putting in the `cv` parameter:

```
<div id="div1" align="center"><a href="#" data-cv="do_stuff"><img src='images/icon.png' border='0'></a></div>
...
<div id="div2" align="center"><a href="#" data-cv="do_stuff"><img src='images/icon.png' border='0'></a></div>
```

...and then bind the clicks with jQuery something like this:

```
$("a[data-cv]").click(function() {
   var thediv = $(this).parent(),
       cv = $(this).attr("data-cv");

   thediv.html('<div align="center"><img src="images/loader.gif"/></div>');

   var url = "process.php";
   $.post(url, {contentVar: cv} ,function(data) {
      thediv.html(data);
   });

   return false;
});
```

This code uses the [has attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) to get all anchor elements that have a `data-cv` attribute and binds a click handler to those elements. Within the handler, `this` will be the particular anchor clicked, so given in your markup the associated div element is actually the parent of the anchor you can just use `$(this).parent()` to get a reference to the right div (for other html structures you could use other DOM traversal methods such as `.prev()`, or `.closest()`, etc.).

The `return false;` at the end of the click handler stops the default anchor click behaviour.

Note also that for your code as currently shown you don't need the `.show()` method since the divs are already showing.

Answer (score -1):

clear the html of your div as before adding new div the like :

```
$('#myDiv').html('');
```